# Traefik route 404

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to host a few different websites on a single Raspberry Pi using Docker. I was told that I would need to use something like Traefik to route everything properly.

I tried using the Docker Basic Example under User Guides in their documentation as a test. I followed along with the example and created the `docker-compose.yml` file and copied in the example from the docs:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
    # - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

Using this example going to the devices local IP I recieve a page that simply says:

> 404 Page not found

I've tried changing the Traefik container image version, and editing the example with my relevant information as well as recreating the example on another host and still I receive the above 404.

Am I doing something incorrect with Traefik to receive this 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user guide you have mentioned, there is this note:

> Replace whoami.localhost by your own domain within the traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule label of the whoami service.

So, after you replace `whoami.localhost` with you local IP, you should be able to see `whoami` service responding correctly.

Comment: Doing so gives me the same 404

Comment: Disregard my last comment, i seem to be a fool!

Comment: Changing the IP to my devices localhost has seem to fixed my issue and display the whoami correctly.

Comment: The stack exchange app is terrible and is creating a separate post instead of posting it on a new line. Upon changing it to my local IP seems to work. But if I try accessing it via my domain name it gives me the same error. Do i have to add in another line for the domain name?

Comment: You just need to route your domain name to your local IP in `hosts` file. Then you can replace your local IP in `Host` rule with your domain name and everything should work.

Comment: That seems to have perfectly worked! Thank you so much!! Im guessing to add in another website I just need to recreate the same steps but with another domain.